# Removing entry from Google Authenticator

Tags: google-authenticator

I'd like to remove one of the items from my Google Authenticator app but I cannot find any option to do so.

There is [a Q&A on the Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/280429/95704) which suggests there should be a Pencil icon to edit them. However, on my phone (Pixel 6 Pro), there is only an option to Add a new item, and Settings only shows the option to adjust the date/time correction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long-press the entry to select it, then tap "Remove" (trash bin icon) on the top-right corner.